# BitMovin - Unable to connect Amazon S3 Output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am setting up an Amazon S3 output on BitMovin and it is telling me my values are incorrect. I don't know which ones because they all have been copied and pasted over. It may be another issue with my bucket.

I have setup a bucket in Oregon so `us-west-2`, copy and pasted the name, access key and access secret in. My policies match what they have on this document too:

[Tutorial: Policies for BitMovin](https://bitmovin.com/faq/create-aws-s3-bucket-can-used-output-location/)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Copy&Paste went wrong, but just a bit :)

In your second statement, you would have to remove the "/*"-part from the string "arn:aws:s3:::test-bitmovin/*" within the "Resource"-Array.

The allowed actions of the second statement apply to the bucket but not to the objects within. Therefore the stated resource should refer to a bucket.

Then it should work as expected!